Join condition apparently ignored in joinWith
I'm using code like this:
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._

case class Conversions(
    date: String,
    currency: String,
    rate: String
)

val usdConversions: Dataset[Conversions] = Seq(
    Conversions("19990811", "EUR", "0.1"),
    Conversions("19990811", "KPN", "0.2"),
    Conversions("19990812", "EUR", "0.3"),
    Conversions("19990812", "KPN", "0.4"),
).toDS

val usdToEurConversions = usdConversions.where($"currency" === "EUR")

usdConversions.joinWith(usdToEurConversions, 
    usdConversions("date") === usdToEurConversions("date")
).show(false)

On my company's computer (Spark 3.1.2) and on the server (Spark 3.1.1) I get:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  _1|                  _2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
|{19990811, KPN, 0.2}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990811, KPN, 0.2}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
|{19990812, KPN, 0.4}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990812, KPN, 0.4}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
+--------------------+--------------------+

While on my personal computer (Spark 3.3.0) I get:
+--------------------+--------------------+
|_1                  |_2                  |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990811, KPN, 0.2}|{19990811, EUR, 0.1}|
|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
|{19990812, KPN, 0.4}|{19990812, EUR, 0.3}|
+--------------------+--------------------+

Which is what I was actually expecting.

From this answer I learned an approach that seems to work on Spark 3.1
usdConversions.alias("ds1")
    .joinWith(
        usdToEurConversions.alias("ds2"), 
        col("ds1.date") === col("ds2.date")
).show(false)

I still don't know why my initial approach doesn't work on 3.1, since it follows the format as shown on all tutorials.
